# How to get file size from file path with js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, web-frontend

I want to get the size of a file from this path:

> my-path/filename

How can I get the size of this file?

Comment: Is that a file path or a URL? It *looks* like a URL with the schema missing, but the answer will be very different if it is one.

Comment: Why are you marking the file path / URL as a **quote**? Who are you quoting? Please take care to format your questions correctly.

Comment: You'll need to make a request. If the server reports back a correct Content-Length header, a HEAD request will probably do; otherwise you'll have to request the full thing.

Comment: Crazy I can not find a dupe with an accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) method and only set the request method to `HEAD`.

```
    const fetchResponse = await fetch(src, { method: 'HEAD' });
    const size = fetchResponse.headers.get('content-length');
```

Beware, it will return a number represented as a string.

Comment: you can auto convert to a number by putting a + before fetchResponse. 
`const size = +fetchResponse.headers.get('content-length');`

Comment: but when using the + be aware of values like null, true, false and such.